# How can I negate this expression

Tags: regex-negation

*I have absolutely no clue how to work with regex's. I am less than a beginner.*

I want to find any invalid css names from a string, so I can exclude them. Looking online I found a way to select the valid names using this:

```
/-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*/g
```

What I want to do is *negate* this expression, so that only '1999' is matched in this example input:

```
holding-page single 1999 contact id-12 contact single single
```

Comment: I rolled back your edit because it added details of your anguish, but nothing relevant to the actual question. This version keeps it simple yet has everything needed to be clear and answerable. Please refrain from further edits unless you are sure they add value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "negate" an expression, turn it into a *negative look ahead*:

```
/(?<!\S)(?!-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\S+(?!\S)/g
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/2OinTZOlxH).

What this does is match a complete term, but one that does *not* match your positive regex.

A "complete term" is matched using `(?<!\S)\S+(?!\S)`, which is `\S+` (one or more non-whitespace) wrapped in negative look arounds for not a non-whitespace to prevent matching *part* of a term.
Note that "not a non-whitespace" is **not** the same as "whitespace", because "not a non-whitespace" also matches the start and end of the input, so leading and trailing terms that are invalid will match too.

Your positive regex has been turned into a negative look ahead by enclosing it in `(?!...)`.

Comment: Thank you Bohemian. I appreciate the detailed explanation too. I'm surprised the process of turning it into a reliable 'negative look ahead' requires so much more work (more than I expected). This has intrigued me to play around with this and see what else it can do. Thanks again.